# What certificate authorities does Internet Explorer trust?

Tags: ssl, https, web

What certificate authorities do the browsers trust by default? Do these differ between internet explorer, firefox, chrome, safari.... and is there somewhere you can see this? Or is it simply if it is a certificate authority browsers trust it and if it self signed, browsers don't? If thats the case why do some companies provide free ssl certificates?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to find the policies and members lists for Windows/IE from the following links:

- http://support.microsoft.com/kb/931125
- http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/windows-root-certificate-program-members.aspx

In addition, here are some links for other browsers/OSes:

- http://www.mozilla.org/projects/security/certs/included/
- http://www.apple.com/certificateauthority/

This being said, these are for the default lists provided with the software. It's usually possible for system administrators to change this list (for adding new CA certificates in a corporate environment, for example). In IE, if you go in the internet options, you should be able to check the list of root CAs and intermediate CAs. Other browsers also have similar options.

A slight exception to this is for EV certificates, where the signatures are hard-coded in the browsers for them to be recognized as EV CAs (although I would think the CA also needs to be in the trusted list, not just hard-coded for being EV enabled).

Answer (score 0):

As you stated, not every certificate is recognized by default, especially the cheaper ones. So those are more suitable for intranet applications etc. and debugging. For Live websites you really need to make sure they are supported, otherwise your users will be shown an ugly warning.

As to your question about `self signing` vs `certificate authorities`etc, no that's not the case.